# hibernate foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

i have entity A that has foreign key to entity B,  does entity B need to have foreign key back to entity A? if yes, how?
coz entity B, id already used for primary key

entity A --> id, entity_a_name, foreign_key_entity_B  
entity B ---> id, entity_b_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your mapping is fine as is.

Comment: @cometta I have seen many projects :-) Our current application involves 830 tables, 30 000 columns and around 2000 foreign keys. Your need is very simple, so I feel confident that other people would confirm that I am not mistaken ;-) Have a good day! :-)